# nodejs -> OAuth2 Azure AD -> Error AADSTS50001

Tags: node.js, azure, passport.js, oauth-2.0

I want to allow my users to access my WebApp using their Office 365 account in the same way that I already did with Twitter, Facebook and google.
I have already created a WebApp in Azure AD.

I'am using nodejs, passportjs and passport-azure-oauth2 strategy.

In Azure AD, the Web application is Multitenant and the SIGN-ON URL IS "https://nudniq.com"

APP ID URI: "https:\nudniq.com"
Reply URL: "https:\nudniq.comauth\microsoft\callback"
User Assignment required to access app: NO

**Note: I'am using back shlashes instead of slashes in the URL's posted here because stackoverflow only allows me to write no more than two links.**

The only permision that I ask for is:

```
Read all users' basic profiles
```

I'am creating my strategy with this values:

```
clientID: '<client_id>',
clientSecret: '<client_secret_key>',
callbackURL: 'https://nudniq.com/auth/microsoft/callback'
```

But I receive the following error:

```
TokenError: AADSTS50001: Resource identifier is not provided. 
Trace ID: 95f88f5a-95b9-4d3a-86fe-19ae0bbfcc76 
Correlation ID: b056150c-debd-469d-963b-ea362ca93884 
Timestamp: 2016-06-29 01:38:39Z
   at AzureOAuth2.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/home/ec2-user/test2/fastpass/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:298:12)
   at AzureOAuth2.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/home/ec2-user/test2/fastpass/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:345:16)
   at /home/ec2-user/test2/fastpass/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:171:43
   at /home/ec2-user/test2/fastpass/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:177:18
   at passBackControl (/home/ec2-user/test2/fastpass/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:123:9)
   at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/test2/fastpass/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:143:7)
   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
   at _stream_readable.js:908:16
   at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

Please help me, I dont know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are use [AzureOAuthStrategy](https://github.com/andrewkeig/passport-azure-oauth2) strategy, when you occur this issue, it means you have miss configured the `resource` parameter.

According the code sample in the repository at GitHub:

```
this.passport.use("provider", new AzureOAuth2Strategy({
  clientID: config.clientID,
  clientSecret: config.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: config.callbackUri,
  resource: config.resource,
  tenant: config.tenant,
  prompt: 'login',
  state: false
}
```

we need to configure this `resource` parameter.
As you are Office 365 to authenticate your users, please try to set `resource` to `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

Additionally, please regenerate your AAD application's Secret key, and keep it save in your application, do not expose them to public.

Any update, please feel free to let me know.